# nested custom properties not reactive

Tags: css

I have the following approach to spacing

```css
:root {
  --space-unit:  1em;
  --space-xxxs:  calc(0.25 * var(--space-unit));
  --space-xxs:   calc(0.375 * var(--space-unit));
  --space-xs:    calc(0.5 * var(--space-unit));
  --space-sm:    calc(0.75 * var(--space-unit));
  --space-md:    calc(1.25 * var(--space-unit));
  --space-lg:    calc(2 * var(--space-unit));
  --space-xl:    calc(3.25 * var(--space-unit));
  --space-xxl:   calc(5.25 * var(--space-unit));
  --space-xxxl:  calc(8.5 * var(--space-unit));
}
```

so throughout my application I use styles like

```css
.my-component {
  padding: var(--space-md);
}
```

I expected to be able to manipulate `--space-unit` and adjust padding throughout

```html
<div class="parent-wants-more-padding">
   <div class="my-component">...</div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent-wants-more-padding {
  --space-unit: 1.5em;
}
```

but changing `--space-unit` doesn't seem to change the padding on `.my-component` like I hoped it would.

if I lose the nesting and access `--space-unit` directly

```css
.my-component {
  padding: calc(1.25 * var(--space-unit));
}
```

changing `--space-unit` does actually result in additional padding but obviously is less desired than using the simpler `space-xs`, `space-sm`, `space-md`, etc. Is it possible to have reactivity through nested properties? Or maybe another approach?